# recursive directory listing in java

Tags: java, list, directory

//The method doesn't run in the console.
I tried to initialize it in main too , but nothing worked
The purpose is to write a recursive method the finds and lists directories and sub directories, and stops when there is no directory.

```
package Folders;

import java.io.File;
//lists
//isFile
/**/

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Object directoryName;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // String listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories a = new
        // listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories();
        /*
         * listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories a = new
         * listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(); System.out.println(); File file1 =
         * new File("C:\\"); String[] files = file1.list(); for(String string :
         * files) { System.out.println(string); }
         */
    }

    public class listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories {
        public void listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(String directoryName) {
            // directoryName = "C:\\";
            File file1 = new File("C:\\");
            String[] files = file1.list();
            for (String string : files) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
            File directory = new File(directoryName);

            // get all the files from a directory
            File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
            for (File file : fList) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("fdadfa");
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the code sample, everything in your main method commented out, which would explain why "it doesn't work"... Is that actually the case in the code you tried?

Comment: need to edit the the question as per procedure.

Comment: no its another thing i tried

Comment: Can you be more specific about "nothing worked"? What exactly didn't happen that you expected or wanted  to happen?  What, if anything,  _did_ happen that you didn't expect or want?  Did you get any error messages?  Did your computer burst into flames?

Comment: Also, you are constructing a `listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories` object but never calling its `listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories` method (extremely poor choice of method name - a method with the same name as the class is normally the constructor so this is very confusing) so actually the program does nothing.

Comment: it was supposed to print  the fallowing directories to the console.and i called this method from main , still nothing happend

Comment: In the code you show, there's **no call** to that method. None whatsoever, not even in the comments. As you seem uninterested or unwilling to provide the real details of what you tried and did, I'm voting to close this question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recursively print file names inside directories, change your method as per given below: -

```
public static void listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(File directoryName) throws Exception {

    for(File file : directoryName.listFiles()) {
        if(file.isDirectory())
            listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file);
        else if(file.isFile())
            System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @fvu. What exactly is your question @Tomar?